# Adding values to multiple Tables Using Linq

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Consider I have 2 tables `EmpDetails` and `SalaryTable`.

- `EmpDetails` has columns `EmpName` and `EmpID` (primary key)
- `SalaryTable` has columns `EmpID (foreign key)`, `EmpSalary` and `EmpSalID (primary key)`

When I create a new employee, I want to add `EmpName` to `EmpDetails` and `EmpSalary` to `SalaryTable` with `EmpID` as foreign key.

Currently what I am doing is add `EmpDetails` first, then get the id and then add `EmpID` and `Salary`.

Two sets of code. Can I do it in one go using Entity Framework (Linq)? Is my question since due to network issue some times only one data is entered. Also delete all data using `EmpID` in one go

Comment: Since you have two separate table - you'll always have two separate insert steps. You cannot insert into two tables at once.

Comment: @marc_s can i delete the data in one go?

Comment: No - again - you cannot delete from more than one table at once in any RDBMS that I'm aware of.

Comment: Have you considered to use transactions to have consistency guarantee? Your insertions and deletions would be treated then as one atom operation from the client point of view. (Either succeed both or none of them.)

Comment: @PeterCsala nope i dont knw what that is

Comment: [Here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/transaction-in-entity-framework.aspx) you can find some basic introduction